# How do you know which conda channel to install from?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, conda, conda-forge

When installing a package using `conda intall`, **how do you know which channel to use?**

- `conda install` *packagename* (default channel)
- `conda install -c anaconda` *packagename*
- `conda install -c conda-forge` *packagename*
- `conda install -c some-other-channels` *packagename*
  ・
  ・
  ・

I know people say channels don't really matter, but I came across the issue when installing `jupyter` -
When I tried `conda install jupyter`, there was an error `ImportError: DLL load failed` when setting up `jupyter notebook`.
However when I tried `conda install -c anaconda jupyter`, it worked fine.

There are `jupyter` packages offered by different channels when you search on [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/search?q=jupyter) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: you don't. I'd advise to use `conda-forge` as one having much wider selection of packages and their latest versions. There are also some other differences, e.g. `conda-forge` favours `openblas` over `mkl` that you can find in the default `anaconda`.

Normally you should not worry about which channel to use, just add all the channels you need and ask `conda` to maintain priority:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install <package>
```

I highly recommend [this read](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html) in Anaconda docs that explains how it manages priorities and selects the right channel.

There might be some rare cases, like yours, where for whatever reason the `anaconda` was a better choice. I'd hypothesize that it's because you opted for the old Jupyter. Mind that it's been years now since JupyterLab superseded Jupyter and there's less attention put into maintaining the old version (it's supposed to be only important bug and security fixes).

It can also happen that the package you're looking for is neither in `anaconda` nor `conda-defaults` - or the version you find there is really old. If in doubt, search for the package either directly with `conda` or through the [web site](https://anaconda.org/search). For instance, for latest `plotly` I have to use `plotly` channel.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I agree that I should switch to JupyterLab as well, though I always wonder when exactly is the best timing to switch to or update anything (not just Jupyter but any packages, libraries). People say "avoid update if it's still in beta mode" or "it's safe to stick to a version that is one major point revision behind the current one", how do you manage the version updates?

Comment: @koyamashinji In this case it is a high time to switch. JupyterLab hit 1.0 in August 2019 and even before that was already a reliable tool. The user experience is great, beats out of the water the old Jupyter. I love how I can put contextual help next to the code, and in general use well the real estate. The only thing to be aware is that you'll have a trouble looking at old Jupyter after getting the hang of JupyterLab. If I answered your question, consider accepting the answer. Cheers!